# Pandas Groupby count on multiple columns for specific string values only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame([
('01/09/2020', 'TRUE', 'FALSE'),
('01/09/2020', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'),
('02/09/2020', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'),
('02/09/2020', 'TRUE', 'FALSE'),
('03/09/2020', 'FALSE', 'FALSE'),
('03/09/2020', 'TRUE', 'TRUE'),
('03/09/2020', 'TRUE', 'FALSE')], columns=['date', 'Action1', 'Action2'])
```

[image]

Now I want an aggregation of 'TRUE' action per day, which should look like
[image]

I applied group by, sum and count etc but nothing is working for me as it i have to aggegate multiple columns and I don't want to split the table into multiple dataframes and resolve it indivisually and merge into one, can someone please suggest any smart way to do it.

Comment: are the TRUE and FALSE meant to be strings or can they be bool?

Comment: as of now its string only, as the data collector place some non-boolean values in between so can't change it bool

Comment: Don't choose my answer.  The answers by Quang Hoang and Vaishali are way better.  This will bother me greatly if you don't change it.

Comment: I usually favor `.resample` as we can change aggregation to any time period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone seeing this answer should look at the answers by [@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66783324/2336654) or [@Vaishali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66783293/2336654)
They are much better answers.  I can't control what the OP chooses, but you should go upvote those answers.

#### Inspired by [@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66783324/2336654)

```
dummy.iloc[:, 1:].eq('TRUE').groupby(dummy.date).sum()

            Action1  Action2
date                        
01/09/2020        2        1
02/09/2020        1        1
03/09/2020        2        1
```

---

#### OLD ANSWER

Fix your dataframe such that it has actual `True`/`False` values

```
from ast import literal_eval

dummy = dummy.assign(**dummy[['Action1', 'Action2']].applymap(str.title).applymap(literal_eval))
```

Then use `groupby`

```
dummy.groupby('date').sum()

            Action1  Action2
date                        
01/09/2020        2        1
02/09/2020        1        1
03/09/2020        2        1
```

Answer (score 7):

True and False in your dummy df are strings, you can convert them to int and sum

```
dummy.replace({'TRUE':1,'FALSE':0}).groupby('date',as_index = False).sum()

    date        Action1 Action2
0   01/09/2020  2       1
1   02/09/2020  1       1
2   03/09/2020  2       1
```

Comment: OP, by all that is good in the world, please use this much more reasonable way to replace the `'TRUE'`/`'FALSE'` strings! (-:

Answer (score 5):

You can also try:

```
dummy.set_index(['date']).eq('TRUE').sum(level='date')
```

Output:

```
            Action1  Action2
date                        
01/09/2020        2        1
02/09/2020        1        1
03/09/2020        2        1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [7]: dummy
Out[7]:
         date Action1 Action2
0  01/09/2020    TRUE   FALSE
1  01/09/2020    TRUE    TRUE
2  02/09/2020   FALSE    TRUE
3  02/09/2020    TRUE   FALSE
4  03/09/2020   FALSE   FALSE
5  03/09/2020    TRUE    TRUE
6  03/09/2020    TRUE   FALSE


In [9]: dummy.groupby(['date'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.eq('TRUE').sum())
Out[9]:
         date  Action1  Action2
0  01/09/2020        2        1
1  02/09/2020        1        1
2  03/09/2020        2        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pivot table:

```
dummy.pivot_table(index='date', values=['Action1', 'Action2'], 
                  aggfunc=lambda x: (x=='TRUE').sum()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
          date  Action1 Action2
0   01/09/2020        2       1
1   02/09/2020        1       1
2   03/09/2020        2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

On the similar path using `.resample`

```py
...
dummy['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dummy['date'], dayfirst=True)
dummy[['Action1', 'Action2']] = dummy[['Action1', 'Action2']].replace({'TRUE':True, 'FALSE': False})

# set date to index
dummy.set_index('date', inplace=True)

dummy.resample('1D').sum()
```

See [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) documentation